# Runtime Error in Visual Simulation Environment - Microsoft Robotics Studio

Tags: simulation, visual-programming, robotics-studio

I am using Microsoft Robotics Studio for a school project and I am getting a strange error when I try to run the Visual Simulation Environment. It was working fine until yesterday and then suddenly it gave me a runtime error saying "Illegal command line arguments... do not use VPLHost directly, use dsshost instead to run a manifest" But I am only clicking on Run in VPL/DSS Manifest editor.

I am running MRDS as administrator and I even tried re-installing MRDS but it is still showing the same MS VPL Runtime error. I tried to search online, but cannot find any suitable solution.

I already tried running the existing samples, I.e. Urban Environment, Multiple Simulated Robots etc. but it still gives me the same error. The strange thing is that it was working perfectly one minute, and then started giving me this error message the next minute, when I had not changed anything in between. In fact, I had wanted to change something in my manifest, so I closed the running VPL application, closed VPL and opened DSS manifest editor, and ran my manifest and that is when I got this error.

What is going wrong? Is some MRDS script using vplhost32.exe instead of dsshost? If so, then where and how do I change it?

I tried running the urban envrionment manifest from the command prompt and Using DSSHost32 directly. This time, it didn't give me a runtime error but an intiialization error. I tried changing port numbers but it still doesn't work. I have deleted many files from my computer to free space (JIC) and it still doesn't work. The window just doesn't open even when I hover over it in Windows 7.

The error message looks like this: ***Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted***."

This was even after I checked netstat for free ports and tried but I get this error message. Its either this one or the "Don't use VPLHost directly" if I run it through VPL or DSS Manifest Editor.

Could it be that some external services are interfering with DSSHost/VPLHost? Are there any such services which I could try killing? ANY help/suggestion would help right now as my project is due Thursday and this is a really unfortunate time for it to be acting up like this.

Answer (score 0):

Does the problem reproduce after logging off & logging back on?  It's likely that you had a process hanging around that you weren't aware of.  Logging off should shut down any processes you personally started.